# Specify a line break point for mobile/responsive design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, line-breaks

I need to break a line at a specific point in mobile/small views. For instance, I'd like the text « Commune : CENON-SUR-VIENNE » to break after the colon character. Is there a syntax that allows to specify this manually instead of leaving Bootstrap CSS doing it automatically?

I include a piece of my HTML code below. I have well specified the meta tag inside the `<head>` :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Screenshot :

[image]

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div>
        <h4>Commune : CENON-SUR-VIENNE</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you could try this. https://jsfiddle.net/5vwh46f8/1/

Putting the second word in a span and adding a style inline-block.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="col-lg-5">
  <div>
  <h4>Commune : <span>CENON-SUR-VIENNE</span></h4>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<style>
h4 span{
display: inline-block;
} 
</style>
```

Answer (score 24):

Use a "responsive" `<br>` tag:

```html
<style>
br.responsive {
  display: inline; // Show BR tag for narrow screens
}

@media (min-width: 320px) { // or whatever you are after
  br.responsive {
    display: none; // Hide BR tag for wider screens
  }
}
</style>


Some text <br class="responsive" /> more text.
```

Answer (score 19):

The more straightforward option is to use the [display classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) built-in to Bootstrap and hide a `<br />` based on screen size.

```
<h4>Commune : <br class="d-md-none" />CENON-SUR-VIENNE</h4>
```

The use of columns or wrapping content in spans is overkill; just throw in a little display class and show/hide as needed.

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap, this is the canonical answer.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid breaking on a hyphen, use a non-breaking hyphen character. [(U+2011)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm)

```css
h4 { width: 200px }
```

```html
<h4 class="using regular hyphen">Commune : CENON-SUR-VIENNE</h4>
<hr>
<h4 class="using non-breaking hyphen">Commune : CENON‑SUR‑VIENNE</h4>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [available classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) "for toggling content across viewport breakpoints". For example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<h4>Commune : <span class="visible-xs-inline"><br></span> CENON-SUR-VIENNE</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a media query could give you better control. What if you only wanted to break on desktop (1) didn't want it to break on mobile (2)?

1. [image]
2. [image: mobile]

The HTML:

```
<div class="col-12 text-center">   
    <h2>If many are doing something, <span class="break-mobile">it must be worthwhile</span></h2>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .title-break {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You Can Manage in responsive style through decrease font-size

Comment: Hi Sarika, not exact the solution for font-size ...what about the long words. It's not suite for long words.

Comment: Ya, Sayed, I agree with You, Thank You